# Cannot Solve This Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry

I cannot solve this one:
$$
\sin (x + \pi/3) + \cos (x + \pi/3) = 0.
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try squaring both sides of the equation.

Comment: $\tan(x+\pi/3) = -1 \to x + \pi/3 = 3\pi/4 + k\pi.$

Comment: Thank you, it really helped!

Comment: @Dylan Just curious, Is $0^2=1$?

Comment: No. What you get is that $\sin\left(2x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=-1$.

Answer (score 4):

This Expression 
$$ \sin (x + \pi/3) + \cos (x + \pi/3) = 0$$ 
dividing both sides for 
$$ \cos(x+\pi/3) $$
you'll get 
$$ \sin(x+\pi/3)/\cos(x+\pi/3)=-1 $$ 
but this is the same thing that

$$ \tan(x+\pi/3)=-1. $$
 $$ x+\pi/3=3\pi/4+k\pi $$ 
and finally
 $$ x=5\pi/12+k\pi. $$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that,

$x+\pi/3=A$

The equation then becomes,

$\sin A+\cos A=0$

$\implies \tan A + 1 =0$

$\implies \tan A=-1$

$\implies A=\frac{3\pi}{4}+k\pi$

$\implies x+\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{3\pi}{4}+k\pi$

$\implies x=\frac{5\pi}{12}+k\pi$

Answer (score 2):

Given that $$\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=0$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=0$$ $$\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=0$$$$\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}$$ $$\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{12}\right)=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}$$  As there is no information about the unknown $x$, hence writing the general solution we have $$x+\frac{\pi}{12}=2n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$$ $$x=2n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{12}$$ $$\implies \color{blue}{x=2n\pi+\frac{5\pi}{12}}\quad  \text{&} \quad \color{blue}{x=2n\pi- \frac{7\pi}{12}}$$ Where, $\color{blue}{\text{n is any integer}}$